# Pointers and Arrays vs Pointers and Integers C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, integer

I am learning C++ and have become a little confused to how a Pointer to an Integer Value and a Pointer to an Array differ... See my code below:

```
int main(void) 
{
    int* ptrOne;
    int VarOne = 25;

    ptrOne = VarOne; 

    int* ptrTwo;
    int ArrayTwo[6];
    ArrayTwo[0] = 2; //ect for the rest of the array, omitted here.

    ptrTwo = ArrayTwo;
}
```

Pointers are just variables that hold an address.

For the line ptrOne = VarOne, it shoves the VALUE of 25 into ptrOne.

For the line ptrTwo = ArrayTwo, it shoves the ADDRESS of ArrayTwo[0] into ptrTwo.

Why is ptrTwo = ArrayTwo equivalent to ptrTwo = &ArrayTwo[0], but ptrOne = VarOne is NOT equal to ptrOne = &VarOne?

Is this due to the fact the operation is happening to an array vs an int?

Thanks in advance for any help, I have stepping through this code in my compiler and looked at the addresses in memory and the associated values, I did also read the answer for [how to differentiate integer pointer and integer array pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34712598/how-to-differentiate-integer-pointer-and-integer-array-pointer), but it did not fully explain the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is ptrTwo = ArrayOne equivalent to ptrTwo = &Array[0]

Because in C the name of the array is the address of the first element. You may want to check out further why:
[How come an array's address is equal to its value in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c)

> but ptrOne = VarOne is NOT equal to ptrOne = &VarOne?

Because `VarOne` is a single variable, so `VarOne` is the value of the variable itself, not the address of that variable.

Actually this code should be an outright error if you switch on compiler warning (`-pedantic-errors`) which tells you that you can't convert a pointer type to int.

```
error: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

Comment: [Arrays are *not* pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959705/arrays-are-pointers)

Comment: True. I only mentioned the name of the array is the address of its first element.

Answer (score 0):

```
int A[5]={0,1,2,3,4};
```

The name of the array A is a constant pointer to the first element of the array. So A can be considered a const int*. Since A is a constant pointer, `A = NULL` would be an illegal statement. Arrays and pointers are synonymous in terms of how they use to access memory.
 `A[0]` returns **the value in [the pointer of the array's first element]+0** yet returns **the array element with the index of '0'**.

```
int* ptr= A; //= int* ptr= &A[0];
```

So since `int` is considered as a data type we can't use it as a pointer. when we want to declare a static pointer of an `int` value it's written with the following syntax :

```
int X= 25;
int* ptr= &X;
```